# MacOS endless loop, no access to boot menu

Tags: macos

macOS after upgrading to Ventura stopped starting, endless reboot with either just a lighted screen or just apple logo without progress bar, cmd + r and many other "saving" keyboard shortcuts don't work at all.

The only thing available is pressing option on start and access two disks - Mac and Win10 (win10 installed alongside macOS at the same time works) and also recovery over the internet, which eventually after a long wait crashes to error -1008F.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206989 Come back & tell us what happens.

Comment: I checked this but still nothing that helps me

Comment: If you have access to another Mac, Make a USB boot stick on there, otherwise it's take it to an Apple Store.

Comment: I have access to another Mac, but it's with older macos, how do I manage to connect them together, I don't understand

Comment: You make a USB boot stick. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/309400#309400

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error, my mac is 2015 mid. latest os has some issue or might not compatible.only solution until they fix that is reinstall the previous working os from time machine.

Comment: My mac is 2019. How do I reinstall macos when I only have working Windows 10 running on my laptop?